# Is catching a KeyNotFoundException more efficient than checking if the key exists?

Tags: c#, dictionary, try-catch

Assume we have a dictionary with a class as key and index, and we want to return the item if the item exists, else return null. Which of these is more efficient?

```
if(myDictionary.ContainsKey(myKey))
    return myDictionary[myKey];
return null;
```

or

```
try { return myDictionary[myKey]; }
catch { return null; }
```

Comment: If I were to take a guess, unwinding the stack is more expensive than a hash lookup. There's only one way to find out!

Comment: You can always use the `TryGetValue` like `if (myDict.TryGetValue(k, out v)) return v; else return null;`

Comment: If you have a way to avoid an exception, use it.

Comment: Unwinding the Stack is more expensive, also, `Try-Catch` block will add couple of extra instructions in the generated `IL`.

Comment: By thinking about it some more, the first one is theoretically doing the same thing twice. So yeah, dcg's answer is probably the best one, because it theoretically should be doing just 1 lookup instead of 2 and has a cleaner syntax than the second choice.

Comment: Key lookup is amortized O(1) fast, very hard to beat.  It also primes the CPU cache for the next statement.  It all depends on how often it throws, you'll have to measure.  But above all, sooner or later you are going to need to force the debugger to stop when an exception is thrown to debug bad exception handling elsewhere in the program.  You'll curse loudly at this try/catch code.

Comment: @dcg: You could just use `myDict.TryGetValue(k, out v); return v;`, which - unlike your solution - works equally well with value types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While efficiency is a concern that should be considered in software development, it is not the only one. Unless there are some restrictions like performance requirements or saving battery on an embedded or mobile device, usually other non-functional requirements come first. Maintainability (and with it understandability of your code) normally has a higher priority.

Considering that, you should not limit yourself to one option. Use `TryGet` when it is not an error when the value is not present in the dictionary. Use the indexer when you consider a missing value an error.

Having said that, when you check the [the reference source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs) for the actual implementation, both, the indexer and `TryGet` get the value from the `FindEntry`. `TryGet` acquires the default value (cheap) and returns. The indexer does not just return, but *additionally* throws an exception. That makes it more expensive.